# Angular UI Router not using template cache after building with grunt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

After building my application with Grunt, ui.router is still trying to access templateUrl urls. As these have been concatenated by ngTemplates this does not work and I just get a number of 404 errors.

I'm new to this and don't really understand what I'm doing

```
$stateProvider
    .state("home", {
      url: "/",
      views: {
        'master': {templateUrl: '/views/main.html'},
        "view-left@home": {
          templateUrl: '/views/list.html'
        },
        "view-right@home": {
          templateUrl: '/views/page.html'
        }
      }
    })
```

This works when I use grunt serve, but breaks when I build the application

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (main.html, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (page.html, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (list.html, line 0)
```

Let me know if you need more information, I'm not really sure what is relevant.

Edit:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
'clean:dist',
'wiredep',
'useminPrepare',
'concurrent:dist',
'autoprefixer',
'ngtemplates',
'concat',
'ngAnnotate',
'copy:dist',
'cdnify',
'cssmin',
'uglify',
'filerev',
'usemin',
'htmlmin'
]);
```

This is my build task.

Comment: what is does your build task look like?

Comment: @rabble Could you please post your grunt configuration of  'ngtemplates'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I seem to have fixed it. The issue was that in my state, the templateUrl was `'/views/main.html'`, but in the templateCache it was `'views/main.html'` (without the first slash). Removing the first slash from the templateUrls fixed the issue.

Comment: omg i was trying to fix this since two day. Many thanks for the hint.